# Как на Bybit получить position margin?

Tags: математика, криптография

По api получаю такие данные:

```
{
        "positionIdx": 2,
        "riskId": 1,
        "riskLimitValue": "2000000",
        "symbol": "BTCUSDT",
        "side": "Sell",
        "size": "0.004",
        "avgPrice": "27991.725",
        "positionValue": "111.9669",
        "tradeMode": 0,
        "positionStatus": "Normal",
        "autoAddMargin": 0,
        "adlRankIndicator": 2,
        "leverage": "25",
        "markPrice": "28001.97",
        "liqPrice": "29302.70",
        "bustPrice": "29442.60",
        "positionMM": "0.588852",
        "positionIM": "1.119669",
        "tpslMode": "Full",
        "takeProfit": "0.00",
        "stopLoss": "0.00",
        "trailingStop": "0.00",
        "unrealisedPnl": "-0.04098",
        "cumRealisedPnl": "-51.57462434",
}
```

Нужно из них получить **position margin**, в данном случае число **4.5880**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]